# Lebesgue Integral of Sequence Converging to 0 a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is this true w.r.t to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^d}$: If$\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is sequence of measurable functions s.t. $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ a.e., then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f_n(x)| \rightarrow 0$.

If not, what is a counter-example? Moreover, what other conditions in the hypothesis are needed to prove the above?

Comment: It should be obvious that this is not true. Almost everywhere convergence looks at the size of points but _individual_ behaviour at each point, while the integral looks at an _average_ behaviour. So, the basic idea is to make $f_n$ behave "very badly" on a set $S_n$ with mass $m_n \to 0.$ For example, if you make $f_n = a_n \mathbf{1}_{S_n},$ with $a_n > 0,$ then $\int f_n = a_n \lambda(S_n),$ and you can now decide $a_n$ and $S_n$ to make this sequence behaves however badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual counter-example is $f_n(x) = n 1_{]0, 1/n]}(x)$. If you add the condition that $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x) $ for some function $g$ such that $\int g(x) dx < \infty$ then it is true, by the dominated convergence theorem.